# Placing a title on quiverplot (vector field plot) in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

So I found many questions on plotting vector fields.

Some great sources on making these plots would be:

1. [Chapter 4  Graphics with Matplotlib](http://kestrel.nmt.edu/~raymond/software/python_notes/paper004.html)
2. [matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiverkey](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiverkey.html)
3. [Visualizing a vector field with matplotlib](https://scipython.com/blog/visualizing-a-vector-field-with-matplotlib/)
4. [Vector Fields](https://krajit.github.io/sympy/vectorFields/vectorFields.html)

I found many questions on creating these plots on stack exchange. The difference is my question is particularly with regards to adding a title to these plots. The old `plt.title()` did not work to do this. The best solution I had so far was creating a legend with the desired title then forcing it up using the coordinates. My solution however looks horrible.  My question is how does one add a title to a quiver plot/vector plot.

My code so far was

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


%matplotlib inline
x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-20,20,15),np.linspace(-20,20,15))

xdot = x
ydot = x+y
# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
Q = ax.quiver(x, y, xdot, ydot, scale=500, angles='xy') # Quiver key
ax.quiverkey(Q,-10,22,30,"5.1.7",coordinates='data',color='k')
xl = plt.xlabel("x")
yl = plt.ylabel("y")
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Summary

So to summarize my question. How does one add a title to the quiver plot above. Could you please provide a solution with the plot.

Sorry if this is a trivial question I am relatively new to both Python and plotting quiver plots. I am using google colab rather than jupyter if that could influence anything.

Comment: `plt.title()` works for me. Can you include the versions of packages you are using? And how you are running the code (I assume jupyter notebook).

Comment: `plt.title()`should work without problems. Just make sure it is not called earlier than `plt.subplots(...)`.  If you 'd have multiple subplots,  `plt.suptitle()` sets an overall title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.title()` should work but the trick is the position that you add it. A good rule of thumb is to add it last just before `plt.show()`  always.